# My router seems to be emitting a hidden network?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, kali-linux

I've recently installed Kali Linux to play with Wi-Fi networks in a lab enviroment within my own home. I initially tried to crack my own Wi-Fi but I have noticed something weird — there is a second network with an RSSI comparable to my actual Wi-Fi network. Is this due to my router being a dual-band router and the second network is actually its second band, and there is some magic that happens between the two bands making them act as a single network, or is there something else I don't understand going on here?

When I do `airodump-ng` against my wireless interface I see two entries with relatively high signal strength:

```
  BSSID   PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID
 [BSSID1] -56        7        0    0   1  54e. OPN              <length:  0>
 [BSSID2] -58       10       10    0   1  54e. WPA2 CCMP   PSK  [My Network's SSID]
```

The fact that the signal strength between the two is relatively close — much closer than any of the random neighbouring networks that are out of my control — leads me to believe they are originating from the same (and only) source I have in my house, which would be my dual-band router with 2 anttennas. Am I correct in my thinking? And if so, why & how does this second BSSID work?

Comment: What model of router do you have?  Unplug power to the router.  Do both networks go away?

Comment: @Steven im actually SSH'ing into the kali machine in my spare time at work... so unfortunately i dont have physical access to try this, but this would of been such an obvious solution i probably wouldnt of even thought of regardless. The router itself is a TPLink TL-ER604W

Comment: Who is your ISP?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 What would that matter? Thats irrelevant to my wifi network.

Comment: @James Trotter: Suit yourself.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 an answer to what that would matter would of been preferable to a passive aggressive retort.

Comment: @JamesTrotter If he hadn't seen your comment mentioning your router, he may have thought you were using, say, a Comcast Xfinity-provided router that by default publishes at least one extra SSID for the same of Xfinity's hotspot roaming service. Or maybe another ISP that does a similar thing.

Comment: @JamesTrotter Can you give us the two BSSIDs, or at least the first half of each? If they don't both have TP-Link OUIs, and neither has the local bit set, then it's probably not from the same router. If they're both TP-Link and neither has the local bit set, if they're really from the same router I would expect them to be identical except for the last few bits of the last byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these were the main two BSSes of a simultaneous dual-band router, they would be on separate bands. If your `airodump-ng` output is reliable, these two BSSes are on the same band and channel: Channel 1, which is in 2.4GHz. 5GHz channels start at 36 and go up to 165.

Without knowing the BSSIDs, it's possible that these two BSSes are two "Virtual APs" (VAPs) on the 2.4GHz radio of your router. If they *are* both just VAPs on the same radio, the OUI of both BSSIDs should be TP-Link, or one or both of the BSSIDs should have the local bit set (the two's place bit of the first byte). If both BSSIDs have TP-Link OUIs and they're VAPs on the same radio, I'd expect them to be identical down to the last few bits of the BSSID (but that's not guaranteed).

If they both turn out to be coming from your router, it may not be anything to worry about. It may be that TP-Link has a scheme where they publish a second SSID for their setup app to find easily to help you get back into an AP when you know the admin password but messed up the network password. Or maybe the second SSID allows other TP-Link APs to know that this AP is capable of participating in a wireless extension/relay/mesh scheme. Still, it's worth figuring out exactly what it is.